# Can I use rxJS 6 with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, rxjs

With Angular 6 comes rxJS 6 as a dependency.
We can also use rxJS 5 with Angular 6 using `rxjs-compat` module.

But do you have any experience using rxJS 6 with Angular 5?

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to make sure you use pipe(...) see https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, if you try manually by adding `rxjs 6`. You will get the following message.

`@angular/common@5.2.11 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none was installed.`

Comment: Your may be right. I ended up using rxjs 5.5.10. It has the same syntax that the v6.
It means when the project will use Angular 6, rxjs will be update to v6, but no (or a few) code changes.